# Mongodb combining fields to form collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I have several collections in my db.

I need to create a separate collection by getting the fields from different collections something like views in relational tables.

Is there any way to do it in mongodb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the [`DBCollection.find(...)`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html) allowing a subset of keys to be outputted in the query results, it sounds like you really want to do SQL table joins.  You can't do a direct join, but you can use the [`DBRef`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBRef.html) class to simulate something similar to a SQL join.  Also, you can't really do SQL unions, as it's expected that related sets of attributes will be in the same collection.

You might want to check out this [SQL to MongoDB Mapping Chart](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/SQL+to+Mongo+Mapping+Chart).  In general, it's important to remember that MongoDB is schema-less, so you're not tied to using the same column/row structure for each document.  Thus, constructs like views might not be as important when a schema isn't enforced.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB doesn't support views. You have to implement this functionality yourself on the application layer.